# Empty reference slide in beamer

Tags: beamer, bibtex

Help, my PDF displays an empty reference page. Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\section{Overview} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The Shaw prize}
\begin{itemize}
\item Sir Run Run Shaw lived 107 years.\cite{Shaw}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{References}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{References}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Accretion Disks and MRI.bib}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is my .bib file:

```
@misc{Shaw,
  title = {The Shaw Prize Website}
}
```

Comment: Not quite a MWE (it's doubtful that `amsmath` and related packages are relevant, for example, and there's a missing `\end{frame}`), but close enough. When you run `bibtex` after running `pdflatex`, you should have seen an error of `White space in argument---line 33 of file (something).aux: \bibdata{Accretion Disks and MRI.bib}`, with a line break between "Accrection" and "Disks". Rename your bib file to something without spaces, and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things: first don't have spaces in the file name of bib file, make it `AccretionDisksandMRI.bib` for example and second, don't use the extension for file name in `\bibliography{AccretionDisksandMRI}`

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{AccretionDisksandMRI.bib}
  @misc{Shaw,
  title = {The Shaw Prize Website}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\section{Overview}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The Shaw price}
\begin{itemize}
\item Sir Run Run Shaw lived 107 years.\cite{Shaw}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{References}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{References}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{AccretionDisksandMRI}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]